# captcha example using angularjs button click validate

Tags: jquery, angularjs

i tried this requirement i got the captcha validate in j query but i want to validate angular click button.please see my fiddle once try to solve please help me. thanks in advance.please press refresh button in my fiddle then only Captcha code is generate.please solve that on-load also

i want to execute the same code using angular. how to change jquery to angular please anyone change that to angular code or i want to validate using ng-click

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.submit=function(){
    alert("hi");
    }
});

function Captcha() {
    var alpha = new Array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        var a = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
        var b = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
        var c = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
        var d = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
        var e = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
        var f = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
        var g = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
    }
    var code = a + ' ' + b + ' ' + ' ' + c + ' ' + d + ' ' + e + ' ' + f + ' ' + g;
    document.getElementById("mainCaptcha").value = code
}
function ValidCaptcha() {
    var string1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('mainCaptcha').value);
    var string2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);
    if (string1 == string2) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
function removeSpaces(string) {
    return string.split(' ').join('');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hspxaeqa/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below jsFiddle

[captcha in Angularway](https://jsfiddle.net/SantoshVasista/6jqmv68d/1/)

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
$scope.submit=function(){
alert("hi");
}

$scope.Captcha = function() {
var alpha = new Array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z');
var i;
var code = "";
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    code = code + alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)] + " ";
}
$scope.mainCaptcha = code;
}

$scope.ValidCaptcha = function () {
var string1 = removeSpaces($scope.mainCaptcha);
var string2 = removeSpaces($scope.c);
if (string1 == string2) {
    alert(true);
}
else {
    alert(false);
}
}

removeSpaces = function (string) {
return string.split(' ').join('');
}

});
```

Comment: thanks. but i want to validate submit button also.. will u help me please its my humble request

Comment: thanks for your help. may be i wasted 1day for that. thanks a lot

Comment: if i dont want to validate with any button.. i want to validate with same textbox suppose if i entered wrong in that textbox it shows error.. is it possible please

Comment: use ng-blur and ng-focus on input element id "txtInput"